# Using method FindAll in two generic lists

Tags: vb.net, generic-list, findall

I've got two generic lists in a vb.net program. I'd like to loop List_A and search List_A.ID in List_B, elements in common should be stored in a third list (LIST).

```
For Each n As BE_Busq In List_A

    LIST = List_B.FindAll(Function(x As BE_Busq) x.ID = n.ID)
    '' for each step, LIST should be incremented, not be replaced
Next
```

Method FindAll will return a generic list. How to increment LIST and not replaced it for each step in loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `AddRange` method to add multiple items to a List.

```
For Each n As BE_Busq In List_A
    LIST.AddRange(List_B.FindAll(Function(x As BE_Busq) x.ID = n.ID))
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
LIST.addrange(List_B.FindAll(Function(x As BE_Busq) x.ID = n.ID))
```